# Is it possible to run multiple versions of MySQL Workbench?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, mysql-workbench

I'm doing an application migration from MySQL 5.5 to workbench v8... 5.5 supports MySQL Workbench up to version 6.3... However, MySQL server 5.5 only supports up to version 6.3 of the workbench.

I have an instance of MySQL server 8.0 on the same machine also that I need to manage.  Is it possible to have two different versions of MySQL Workbench installed on a Windows 10 dev machine at the same time?

Answer (score 2):

I don't see why not. Are you encountering errors installing two versions at once if you specify different install paths? You may have to use different versions of the MySQL installer as well.

It does look like Workbench 8 is [compatible MySQL 5.5, though](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-intro.html) (and I can confirm because I have been using it). The documentation says some queries will not work like showing the processlist (although I just tested this and I can SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST of my MySQL 5.5 server with MySQL workbench 8.0.12.)

Comment: I'm only given an option to upgrade the existing version 6.3 even though I want to leave it alone

Comment: I believe if you move your current 6.3 install out of the default directory, MySQL installer won’t “find” it and your only option will be installing 8 as well. I can test tomorrow, though.

Answer (score 1):

Download an older/archive version MySQL Workbench from the official site https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/workbench/ looking for the **ZIP Archive** / **..._noinstall.zip** option.

Unzip near the current installation in your system (mine is C:\Program Files\MySQL)

Run the MySQLWorkbench.exe within the new directory ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can install the newest version and download a noinstall.zip that runs without installation to connect to older deployments.
Both are available from the official repository: https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/workbench/

Only some of the versions are available as noinstall.zip, at the time of writing - 6.3.8 and 6.2.5 were the latest I was able to find in their branches.

Answer (score 0):

it is possible,
Launch mysql workbench

```
menu > edit > Preference > others
```

check Allow more than one instance of mysql workbench to run

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem because of the compatibility issues between workbench and the mysqld versions...

Comment: you can keep different version of mysqlworkbench to solve your problem. 
I provide you a way to open multi instance of different version

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this](https://github.com/joaordsoares/MySQL-Workbench5.2.47CE-Portable.git) portable version of workbench 5.2.47 CE for connections to MySQL server 5.xx and the installed version 8 for newer versions of MySQL Server.

Although I use this software with no problems until now, this is **not** from my authorship, use it at your own risk.

Comment: You should explicitly disclose your authorship of the project to which you link. Besides, why would anyone in the 21st century install and run binaries of unknown provenance?

Comment: I've edited it. This is just another option, people are free to run what ever they want.